# Why is Outlook forwarding emails with the ImapDeleted MAPI property set?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Does any body know why Outlook might start suddenly setting the ImapDeleted MAPI property on forwarded emails?

I'm running Exchange 2010 SP1 RU4.

This issue does not occur in OWA. It does occur in Outlook 2010 & Outlook 2003, in online and cached mode. It follows the mailbox to new computers, and does not appear to be a plugin / addin issue as it still occurs when Outlook is started in safe mode. There are no rules configured for sent mail. Doesn't appear to be caused by the transport mechanism either, because I tried using pipeline tracing, and the property is set in the Original.EML file.

Comment: all mailboxes or just one?  Outlook configured for mapi or imap?  I really don't know, never seen that before, but thought that might help other answers.

Comment: Just one mailbox, using MAPI. We have IMAP disabled in our environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the ImapDeleted property was being set on all emails received by the mailbox, and was simply persisting when those mails were forwarded. After moving the mailbox to another database the issue ceased, and we were able to use OutlookSpy to go through the mails which had the property set and remove it.

Since the issue started after moving the mailbox & stopped after moving the mailbox again we suspect some form of mailbox or AD account corruption was the root cause.